# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Jcrop'

Tags: javascript, jquery

if the below script is removed it works fine, otherwise it shows Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'Jcrop'

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Ajaxfileupload-jquery-1.3.2.js" ></script>
```

Here is the code where I get error.

```
  $(function(){

    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
      aspectRatio: 1,
      onSelect: updateCoords
    });

  });
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: updateCoords is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

I bet, you are missing files. Make sure, you have JQuery and Jcrop included.

[This hello world example](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos/tutorial1.html) shows how:

```
<script src="http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
```

If that is not it, check these common causes to this kind of problem:

- You (or some of your libraries) included multiple versions of jQuery.
- You execute or load things in the wrong order:
- Make sure that you load Jcrop *AFTER* jQuery.
- Make sure that you don't call Jcrop after it has been fully loaded.
- Also, make sure that other dependencies are resolved: If you have code A, and that depends on other code B, make sure that B runs before A.

(Of course, you also need the CSS files, but missing CSS files will not cause this kind of error.)

Comment: I have included those two files but it shows error. I think some conflict between jquery files. please help me out.

Comment: @user2990754 Make sure, you only include one jQuery version. Then add Jcrop to the mix. Make sure, they are included in the same order as above: First jQuery, then Jcrop.

Comment: I used only one version and under that I included jcrop.js file but its not working. I have lots of other jquery plugin too. May be that causes problem. :(

Comment: @user2990754 There are two ways to debug this kind of problem: 1. Remove stuff from the non-working version, in steps, until it works. You then narrowed down the issue to your last step. 2. Start from a minimal version and add in steps until it stops working. Keep us posted. :)

Comment: @user2990754 Are you sure that Jcrop is fully initialized at the point you call that function? Also check the other additions to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/HUdM7/1/

Working fine for me.

**HTML:-**

```
<img src="http://jcrop-cdn.tapmodo.com/v0.9.10/demos/demo_files/pool.jpg" id="cropbox">
```

**JS:-**

```
$(function () {    
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
        aspectRatio: 1,
        onSelect: updateCoords
    });
});

function updateCoords(){
}
```

Comment: while doing this thing as separately its working fine but while integrating with another one it shows this kind of error. Actually am integrating ajax photo upload with this jcrop, while integrating it shows error. help me.